# MariaDB setting : Access denied for user 'root'@'ma' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

[update]
I solve the problem by :

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'ma'=PASSWORD('pass');
```

And I still have a question want to ask：
should I set password for `127.0.0.1` and `::1` ???
What's these two root user is???

[image]

[original question]
I have a server 
I can log in DB on the server 
From my computer,I can access ,too.
BUT WHEN I put the code on tomcat on that server
I run the code and got error : `Access denied for user 'root'@'master' (using password: YES)`

I guess it's because my code is `jdbc:mysql://192.168.xx.xx:3306/project`
not    `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/project`

How can I fix this problem?? What should I set ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of `GRANTs`:

For connecting to an IP address or hostname:

```
GRANT ... TO 'user'@'192.2.3.4' ...;
GRANT ... TO 'user'@'host.name' ...;
```

For connecting to `localhost` (alias `127.0.0.1`) -- That is, when the client is on the *same* machine as the server:

```
GRANT ... TO 'user'@'localhost' ...;
```

(Actually, you can use either technique to connect from the same server.)

Comment: I use ````GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-new-password' WITH GRANT OPTION;````   I think it's another problem